# Microtype, raggedright and varwidth doesn't work well with each other

Tags: horizontal-alignment, microtype, varwidth

I am using microtype inside varwidth environment in the way described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241197/microtype-does-not-work-inside-varwidth). It works well with justified text, but now I have very short-lined text like a verse. And sometimes microtype is working, and sometimes does not... Why? Is there solution?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm,nomarginpar, noheadfoot,left=20mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=40mm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{varwidth}

%make microtype work inside varwidth
\makeatletter
\newdimen\@vwid@leftmargin
\newdimen\@vwid@rightmargin

\def\@vwid@sift{%
  \skip@\lastskip\unskip
  \dimen@\lastkern\unkern
  \count@\lastpenalty\unpenalty
  \setbox\z@\lastbox
%{\showoutput\showbox\z@}%
  \ifvoid\z@ \advance\sift@deathcycles\@ne \else
  % --- record left/right margin kerning ---
  \@vwid@leftmargin \leftmarginkern \z@  % <--
  \@vwid@rightmargin\rightmarginkern\z@  % <--
  \sift@deathcycles\z@ \fi
  \ifnum\sift@deathcycles>33
    \let\@vwid@sift\relax
    \PackageWarning{varwidth}{Failed to reprocess entire contents}%
  \fi
%\message{\the\sift@deathcycles: skip \the\skip@; kern \the\dimen@; penalty \the\count@. }%
%\ifhbox\z@\setbox99\hbox to0pt{\unhcopy\z@}\fi  % = message
  \ifnum\count@=\@vwid@preeqp \@vwid@eqmodefalse\fi
%\ifnum\count@=\@vwid@preeqp \message{End equation mode. }\fi
  \ifnum\count@=\@vwid@posteqp \@vwid@eqmodetrue\fi
%\ifnum\count@=\@vwid@posteqp\message{Begin equation mode. }\fi
%\if@vwid@eqmode {\showoutput\showbox\z@}\fi
  \ifnum\count@=\@vwid@toppen % finished
    \let\@vwid@sift\relax
  \else\ifnum\count@=\@vwid@offsets
    \@vwid@setoffsets
  \else
    \ifnum\count@=\@vwid@postw
    \else
      \@vwid@resetb % reset box \z@ or measure it
    \fi
    \@vwid@append
  \fi\fi
  \@vwid@sift}

\def\@vwid@resetb{%
  \setbox\z@\vbox\bgroup
    \ifvoid\z@
    \else
       \ifvbox\z@
         \box\z@
       \else % \hbox
         \@tempdima\hsize
         \advance\@tempdima-\@vwid@roff
         \advance\@tempdima-\@vwid@loff
         \advance\@tempdima-\p@
%\message{Test if \the\wd\z@ > \the\@tempdima, }%
         \ifdim\wd\z@>\@tempdima % full-width line; rebox it
%\message{An ordinary line or alignment. (\the\wd\z@ > \the\@tempdima) }%
            \hbox to\hsize
              {\kern\@vwid@loff
               % --- reinsert margin kerning ---
               \ifdim\@vwid@leftmargin=\z@\else\kern\@vwid@leftmargin\fi % <--
               \unhbox\z@
               \ifdim\@vwid@rightmargin=\z@\else\kern\@vwid@rightmargin\fi % <--
               \kern\@vwid@roff}%
         \else % an equation or direct \hbox
           \if@vwid@eqmode % re-center unnumbered equations
%\message{A centered equation hsize=\the\hsize. }%
              \hbox to\hsize
                {\hskip\@vwid@loff\@plus1fil
                 \unhbox\z@ \hskip\@vwid@roff\@plus1fil}%
           \else % plain narrow \hbox; leave it as-is
%\message{Plain narrow box}%
              \box\z@
    \fi\fi\fi\fi
  \egroup}
\makeatother



\begin{document}


\hfill\begin{varwidth}{.5\textwidth}

\raggedright

Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet

Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed, do

Eiusmod tempor, incididunt ut

Labore et dolore.

Ut enim, ad minim veniam, quis, nostrud

Exercitation ullamco

\end{varwidth}\strut


\hfill\begin{varwidth}{.5\textwidth}

\raggedright

Lorem ipsum, dolor sit

Consectetur adipiscing elit, сonsectetur

Eiusmod tempor,

Labore et dolore.

Ut enim, ad minim

Exercitation ullamco

\end{varwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why do you put a cross by `elit,` but not by `tempor,` ? they are the same thing, the line is short because of the raggedright, just in one case it is not very short,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, but if I put `hfill` before varwidth, I expect that longest line would end right on the border, like in `quis`.

Comment: Protrusion does not make any sense for ragged text. The target of Protrusion is an optically even text border, which is the opposite of ragged typesetting

Comment: @DavidCarlisle why it's all okay in first varwidth? I tried to show that second varwidth is optically (or actually) is more to the left than first varwidth. Maybe it's because microtype is only for justified text as MaxNoe said?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle still, the comma after `elit` should protrude, since it's in the longest line of the varwidth box.

Comment: @Robert arguably:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notwithstanding the question of whether protrusion may be pointless with ragged text, [my patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241197/microtype-does-not-work-inside-varwidth) you referred to is simply incomplete. You also need to add the following:

```
\def\@vwid@measure{%
  \ifvoid\z@
  \else
    % numbered equations not part of alignments can't be reset,
    % so force retention of full width.
    \ifnum\count@=\@vwid@postnump \ifdim\wd\z@<\linewidth
      \ifdim\@tempdima<\linewidth \@tempdima\linewidth \fi
    \fi\fi
    \ifhbox\z@
      \setbox\z@=\hbox
        {\kern\@vwid@loff 
         \ifdim\@vwid@leftmargin=\z@\else\kern\@vwid@leftmargin\fi % <--
         \unhbox\z@ 
         \ifdim\@vwid@rightmargin=\z@\else\kern\@vwid@rightmargin\fi % <--
         \kern\@vwid@roff}%
    \fi
    \ifdim\wd\z@>\@tempdima \@tempdima\wd\z@ \fi
  \fi}
```

[I've now also added this to the other answer.]

Comment: but +1 despite my comments on the question (which I'll prune a bit:-)

Comment: @Robert thank you for patch and for updating it. It is very helpful! Sadly, but it doesn't make uniformity in my case. I know that protrusion is rarely needed within ragged text, but I have this rarest layout.

Comment: @web-stranger do you mean it's not working with your example (it does for me) or with your real-life document? in the latter case, you should amend your question.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Now I put it in the right place! Thank you! It works!